# Duplicate values inside this.state.datasource

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have this block of code that handles the component's state:

```
  componentWillMount(){
    this.state = {
      datasource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2})
    }
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM schedules", [], (tx, res) => {
        let len = res.rows.length;
        if(len > 0) {
          for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            obj.push({id: res.rows.item(i)["id"], title: res.rows.item(i)["title"]})
          }
          this.setState({
              datasource: this.state.datasource.cloneWithRows(obj)
          })
          var data = this.state.datasource;
          console.log(data);
        } else {
          console.log("empty")
        }
      })
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(err))
    })
  }
```

It works like a charm when the app launches the first time. But whenever I re-enter the page again the values inside datasource get duplicated. Shouldn't `rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2` force the ListView not to behave like that or am I missing a logic that needs to be added to the code?

ListView bug example:

```
========================
| First title, id: 1   |
========================
| Second title, id: 2  |
========================
| First title, id: 1   |
========================
| Second title, id: 2  |
```

When I console logged the datasource I saw this property: `_cachedRowCount:15`
Is there a way to force react native not to cache this.state.datasource and re-run every time the page gets open?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving that issue by emptying the `obj` array like so:

```
 db.transaction((tx) => {
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM schedules", [], (tx, res) => {
    let len = res.rows.length;
    if(len > 0) {
      for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        obj.push({id: res.rows.item(i)["id"], title: res.rows.item(i)["title"]}) // Array that needs to be emptied
      }
      this.setState({
          datasource: this.state.datasource.cloneWithRows(obj)
      })
      obj = [] // Done here
    }
  })
}, (err) => {
  console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(err))
})
```